# limits of an integral with delta

Tags: definite-integrals

Having this integral:

$$\int_{x-t}^{x+t}\delta(z)dz$$

the solution is:

$$
  \begin{cases}
                                   1& \text{for $|x| < t$} \\
                                   0 & \text{else} 
  \end{cases}$$

Namely, all the domain of $x-t<z<x+t$ will have $1$ in the integral, but why? Shouldn't I check when $z=x+t=0$ and $z=x-t=0$ so the solution should be:  $1$ when$|x|=t$ else zero? why in the solution all the domain $x-t<z<x+t$  gets 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delta function, $\delta(x)$, is **defined** by
$\int_A \delta(x)dx= 1$ if $0\in A$ and 0 otherwise.

Comment: But why the boundaries are not included in the solution? Namely abs(x)<1 but not abs(x)<=1

Comment: @DannyDan the boundary of the integration domain is a null set with respect to the Lebesgue measure, so it doesn't make a difference: $$\int_{[a,b]} f(x) dx = \int_{(a, b)} f(x) dx.$$

Comment: thank a lot! @Ramanujan